# Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/bind/RelaxedPropertyResolver - microservices

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud

I am working on **Spring Boot + Microservices** project. In this project, have developed `"microservices-dashboard"` project as well.

When I simply run this project, found the below error. I'm using `spring-boot-starter-parent` to `<version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>`

**Error:**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.its.MicroservicesDashboardApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on de.codecentric.boot.admin.config.SpringBootAdminClientAutoConfiguration due to org/springframework/boot/bind/RelaxedPropertyResolver not found. Make sure your own configuration does not rely on that class. This can also happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:646) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.lambda$processDeferredImportSelectors$2(ConfigurationClassParser.java:566) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:563) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:188) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:316) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:271) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:91) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at com.its.MicroservicesDashboardApplication.main(MicroservicesDashboardApplication.java:15) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on de.codecentric.boot.admin.config.SpringBootAdminClientAutoConfiguration due to org/springframework/boot/bind/RelaxedPropertyResolver not found. Make sure your own configuration does not rely on that class. This can also happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:55) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:221) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:636) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/bind/RelaxedPropertyResolver
    at de.codecentric.boot.admin.config.SpringBootAdminClientEnabledCondition.isEnabled(SpringBootAdminClientEnabledCondition.java:59) ~[spring-boot-admin-starter-client-1.3.3.jar:1.3.3]
    at de.codecentric.boot.admin.config.SpringBootAdminClientEnabledCondition.getMatchOutcome(SpringBootAdminClientEnabledCondition.java:45) ~[spring-boot-admin-starter-client-1.3.3.jar:1.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedPropertyResolver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
```

**MicroservicesDashboardApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableMicroservicesDashboardServer
public class MicroservicesDashboardApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MicroservicesDashboardApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: microservices-dashboard

server:
  port: 8083
```

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Actuator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Eureka Server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MS Dashboard Server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>be.ordina</groupId>
            <artifactId>microservices-dashboard-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like Simon Martinelli already said, the microservices dashboard is not compatible with Spring Boot 2.
We are aware of this issue and already did some research on the matter.

Because most of us are not working at a company which has its main focus on open source, we are forced to work on this project during our free time.
Unfortunately due to passed and recent events this project didn't receive the work/love it deserves to have.
However, it **still** is our intention to continue the work on this project.

Answer (score 4):

microservices-dashboard-server is not compatible with Spring Boot 2

And as I see the last commit is older than a year I assume that this is no longer developed.

Comment: I think it must have some replacement then. Are you aware about the same ?